# click the button then pop up a dialogthen submit the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<button onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

js code：

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function(){
                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                            this.form.submit();
                    }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

The above is the normal step. click the button, then submit the form. now, i want to add one step before the form is submitted. the step is. when click the button, it will pop up a dialog. when close the dialog.there are some content on it. then submit the form.

1, i want to use jquery in `productAddToCartForm.submit = function(){....}` .if the page have loaded the jquery library.but i don't know how to add jquery code in the function. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Here is a jsfiddle example of my answer -> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/se8Zt/6/)

If your popup window will be an HTML page, you could bind to the click event on your button, display / close the popup and then call form.submit();

Give your button and form an id:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/formsubmit.html" method="post"></form>
<button id="submitButton" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
```

Then do something like this with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default action

         //show your popup
         //hide your popup

         $('#myForm').submit(); //submit the form

     });
});
```

If there is a button on the popup that the user will click to close it, you could call the submit function by binding to the click event of whatever element is used to close the popup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```
  var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
                productAddToCartForm.submit = function(){
                        if (this.validator.validate()) {
                       $("#YourPopUp").show('slow', function() {
                       $('#YourPopUp').hide(1000,'slow', function() {
                       productAddToCartForm.form.submit();
                       });
                       });
                      }       
                    }
                }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Comment: there are some content on the dialog, how should i do? thank you

Comment: Have a re-look at the answer.